# Automating a mass removal of an outer nested block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have about 900 files that require removing the outermost block, which would be a very tedious and error-prone task to do manually. How can I automate this process?

For instance, I have files that look like the following Ruby example:

```rb
Class1.rb:
# some comments

module OuterModule
  class Class1
    # some code
  end
end

Class2.rb:
# some comments

module OuterModule
  class Class2
    # some code
  end
end
```

The desired output for each file is:

```rb
Class1.rb:
# some comments

class Class1
  # some code
end

Class2.rb:
# some comments

class Class2
  # some code
end
```

Comment: The outermost block is always named Outermodule or could be anything?

Comment: Some editors, like Visual Studio Code, have plugins that will automatically re-indent and format code neatly, so while editing 900 files is a giant hassle, it's basically two line cuts, save, and move on to next file. You could do this with a Ruby script, but it'd probably take longer to write it and test it than to just go ahead and do it. At 2-3 seconds per file, it's about an hour of work at most. Hope you don't have to do this more than once.

Comment: I hope you have version control because any script you use here could go *horribly* awry. If you do have version control, guess you're taking the "blame" here for any code!

Comment: Since Rubocop can automatically fix offenses in Ruby code, you could maybe write a custom cop to remove the outer namespace and have it auto-correct your files. Or maybe fiddle with [rubocop-ast](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-ast) directly.

Comment: I would remove all `module OuterModule` lines and the last line in the file that contains an `end`, both can be done with find and replace in an IDE or editor. And then would use Rubocop to fix the indentation. After that, you will likely have to fix some files that had a different from expected format. Or cases in which the “alternative” syntax `class OuterModule::Class3` was used. Don't forget that the files will need to be moved to allow autoloading to still work.

Comment: @RafaelMoreira, yes, the outermost block is always named `OuterModule`

Answer (score 0):

Let's first construct the two files in the example.

```
s1 = <<_
# some comments

module OuterModule
  class Class1
    # some code
  end
end
_

s2 = <<_
# some comments

module OuterModule
  class Class2
    # some code
  end
end
_
```

```
strings = [s1, s2]
FILES = ["Class1.rb", "Class2.rb"]
```

```
FILES.each_index { |i| File.write(FILES[i], strings[i]) }
```

See [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-read) and[IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-write). Note that `File` is a subclass of `IO` so it inherits `IO`'s methods. One normally sees, for example, `File.read(...)` rather than `IO.read(...)`, but either can be used.

---

Now construct a simple method to display the contents of files.

```
def display_files
  FILES.each_index { |i| puts "-------------", File.read(FILES[i]) }
end
```

As a check examine the two files I've just written.

```
display_files
-------------
# some comments

module OuterModule
  class Class1
    # some code
  end
end

-------------
# some comments

module OuterModule
  class Class2
    # some code
  end
end
```

---

We can use [String#gsub!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) with the following regular expression to modify the contents of these files.

```
RGX = /^module OuterModule\s*$|^end\s*$|^  /
```

Now read each file, modify its contents and write the modified file.

```
FILES.each do |file_name|
  File.write(file_name, File.read(file_name).gsub!(RGX, ''))
end
```

Examine the files that were written.

```
display_files
-------------
# some comments


class Class1
  # some code
end

-------------
# some comments


class Class2
  # some code
end
```

---

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
RGX = /
        ^                       # match beginning of a line
        module\ OuterModule\s*  # match a literal followed by zero or 
                                # more (*) whitespaces (\s)
        $                       # match the end of a line
      |                         # or
        ^                       # match beginning of a line
        end\s*                  # match a literal followed by zero or 
                                # more (*) whitespaces (\s)
        $                       # match the end of a line
      |                         # or
        ^                       # match beginning of a line
        \ \                     # match two spaces (reduce indentation)
      /x                        # invoke free-spacing mode
```

Note that, as a first step, free-spacing mode removes all spaces that have not been protected. Three common ways to protect space characters are to escape them (as I have done), enclose each in a character class (`[ ]`) and replace them with `\s`, denoting a whitespace character. The last is to be used with caution, particularly because line terminators (e.g., `\n`) are whitespaces.

---

Note:

- I have assumed all indentation is two space characters. If that is not the case (e.g., if tabs are used) the regular expression can be modified accordingly.
- For safety, one may choose to write the modified files with new file names (e.g., `"Class1_new.rb"`), then delete the original file (e.g., `"Class1.rb"`) then rename the new file to the old file name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.

I was able to accomplish this by:

1. Using my IDE's Replace in Files feature, search term `module OuterModule` followed by a new line.  Replace term was empty.
2. Replace in Files, search term a new line + `end`.
3. Run `rubocop -a .` in the folder all the files were contained in.